# c++ Find string when given only part of it inside an array like structure

Tags: c++, arrays, string, partial

It's in the form of a word so let's say I'm given the string "foo", and inside my array there are words like "food", "fool", "foo". All three of them should be printed out.

I haven't made a solid attempt at it yet cause I don't know how to wrap my head around it. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You could do something simple, like iterating through each character in the string and checking it against the characters in the string you are trying to match using a separate function. If three characters in a row match the string you are searching for, add it to a vector or something and display them.

```
// Variables
bool charMatched = false;
vector<string> *stringVec = new vector<string>();
int index = 0;
int counter = 0;
string str = "Whatever you are trying to match";

for (char &c : strings[index])  // For each character in string
{
    // Check for match
    if (checkChar(c))
    {
        counter++;
        charMatched = true;
        if(counter == str.length())
            stringVec->push_back(strings[index]);
    }
    else
    {
        index++;
        counter = 0;
            break;
    }
}

bool checkChar(char c)
{
    // Iterator to go through match string
        static string::iterator it = str.begin();

        if (c == *it)
        {
            if (it == str.end())
                it = str.begin();   // Reset iterator
            else
                it++;               // Increment iterator
            return true;
        }

        else
        {
            if (it == str.end())
                it = str.begin();   // Reset iterator
            else
                it++;               // Increment iterator
            return false;
        }
}
```

You will have to tweak it a little to work with an array the way you want it to but something like this should do what you want. I did not run this through a compiler, I wrote it in Notepad so there may be small syntax errors. I hope this helps!

Comment: He needs 50 rep to comment...shouldn't be down voted imo (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9701/why-cant-i-comment-on-this-answer / http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)

Comment: I could not comment, but since you all crucified me so quickly, I have changed it to an answer. Thanks.

Comment: @Blink Removed -1. Keep contributing and you'll get enough rep to comment in no time. Although your code is leaking. You shouldn't dynamically create `stringVec`, why not use an automatic object? And don't use global variables.

Comment: @Blink And you can't have a `for` loop in global scope either. And what is `strings`?

Comment: @Snps Like I said, this is just a rough sketch of what could make this work. This is not how I would set up a .cpp file... It needs to be tweaked. I did not deal with memory management correctly or declare variables correctly. And "strings[]" is an array referring to the array mentioned in the original question. One to hold a series of strings to be checked against.

Comment: @Snps and thank you for helping me out. I'm pretty new on this site.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using `std::string`, you could use `string::find` to see if one string is contained in another.

If you have a vector of strings, you might use that along with (for example) `std::remove_copy_if` to print out all the words from the vector that contain the chosen word:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>


int main() { 
    std::vector<std::string> words{"food", "fool", "foo", "tofoo", "lood", "flood"};

    std::string word = "foo";

    std::remove_copy_if(words.begin(), words.end(),
                        std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"),
                        [&](std::string const &s) {
                            return s.find(word) == std::string::npos;
                        });
}
```

Result:

```
food
fool
foo
tofoo
```